# Getting primary key constraint violation using sequence for value in PostgreSQL (called from Java)

Tags: java, postgresql, thread-safety

I have a Java application that is populating a database in a multithreaded environment (about 100 inserts per second).

I have section that is doing inserts on a table using this to get a primary key:

```
select nextval('my_sequence') as pk_val
```

The code then gets the value as a string and parses it as an integer and uses that for the primary key.

The code is not doing a commit between selects.

The code that gets the key is synchronized on a `private static final Object = new Object();`

The database is empty when the application is started.

What could be causing me to get the same value from the sequence for my primary key?  Do I need to do a commit?  Is the parsing as an integer causing problems?  Is there another reason this could be happening?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE]. Currently, the information is not sufficient to diagnose the problem.

Comment: A sequence will never return the same number twice. So either you are doing INSERTs without the use of the sequence or the process of converting an integer to a string and back to an integer  has a bug. Most probably it's the first reason. But why are you doing that conversion between string and integer back and forth? Why don't you use `Statement.getInt()` to retrieve the generated sequence value?

Comment: The framework the code used has a very generic method that returns database data as a list of row objects and each row object is a list of strings, so I then need to convert the string back to an integer (or maybe more correctly something more like a double)

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, this is a case of the insert code being called from two different places and using a different sequence in the two places. Nothing to do with commits, nothing to do with datatype, nothing to do with getting the int from a string.